# Get all data from first table even no joined entries present in joined table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have four tables, Ledger,AccMaster,AccDetail,AccGroup.

```
CREATE TABLE AccDetail (DetailID int,
                        MasterID int,
                        LedgerID int,
                        Credit decimal(18, 2));
INSERT INTO AccDetail
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 500), (2,2,2,1000);

CREATE TABLE Ledgers (ID int,
                      Name varchar(10),
                      AccGroupID int);
INSERT INTO Ledgers
VALUES (1, 'A', 1),
       (2, 'B', 1);

CREATE TABLE AccMaster (MasterID int,
                        Date date);
INSERT INTO AccMaster
VALUES (1, '2019-11-04'),
       (2, '2019-11-03');

CREATE TABLE AccGroup (ID int,
                       Name varchar(10));
INSERT INTO AccGroup
VALUES (1, 'Accounts'),
       (2, 'Others');

SELECT AL.Name,
       SUM(AD.Credit)
FROM AccDetail AD
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Ledgers AL ON AL.ID = AD.LedgerID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AccMaster AM ON AM.MasterID = AD.MasterID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AccGroup AG ON AG.ID = AL.AccGroupID
WHERE AM.Date = '2019-11-04'
GROUP BY AL.Name;
```

I get the result for only one entry of Ledger table even there are two entries in Ledger table. It's because there is no corresponding entry for that ledger in other tables. I found many answers with left join and right join but nothing works according to my wish.

I would like to get all entries from ledger table even though there is no data in other tables for that ledger.

RESULT I WOULD LIKE TO GET

---

```
| Name  | Credit| 
-----------------
| A     | 500   |
-----------------
| B     |  0    |
-----------------
```

Comment: Can you share your input and expected output?

Comment: Why would you expect multipe rows? `AccDetail` only has **one** row.

Comment: Why join accmaster and accgroup - you don't use anything from them in your query

Comment: I want 0 for ledgers which has no data in accdetail . I have already shared sql fiddle in the quest @xXx

Comment: I removed the findle and put the DDL and DML in your question, @faheemKurikkal, as users shouldn't be expected to visit a different site to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I have updated the sql fiddle, now it uses AccMaster in WHERE codition. AccGroup may be of no use currently @P.Salmon

Comment: 'I would like to get all entries from ledger table' - then you need to drive from ledger not accdetail.

Comment: You code gives what it is supposed to. If you are not getting what you want then: First tell us clearly what you want; otherwise we don't know. Then tell us why you think that code gives it; otherwise, we can only say, that is how SQL works. The error is in *your expectations* so you have to give them. PS  When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it.

Comment: Reference a table in the `WHERE` which you `LEFT JOIN` to will turn the Join into an Implicit `INNER JOIN`. If you need to reference a column in a `LEFT JOIN`ed table, you need to do so in the `ON`.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS Code questions require a [mre]--"minimal" means the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: I have been trying with different joins for a long time, but didnt get the result. Hence, I posted the question. If you people can assist, give the query as answer or as a fiddle. @philipxy I am not getting what you are trying to say. If you can please post the sql query.

Comment: I want to displaying all Ledgers even it doesn't have any corresponding entry in AccDetail. I had mentioned this in question already. That is, there are two ledgers 'A' and 'B'. Hence in the result it should have both ledgers. even 'B' has no entry in accdetail @philipxy

Comment: What is the first thing you don't understand in my comments? What is stopping you from doing the parts that you do understand? Eg: What is the first place where that code doesn't do what you expect? PS I said "tell us clearly what you want". So, if I hand you a row of values, under what condition does it belong in the result? Another way to put that: When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS You have still not clearly said what goes in the result. See my (edited) last comment on how to do that. Please act on all my comments. PS If you want every row of X to be a subrow in the join output then start with X LEFT JOIN .... You say "all entries from ledger" but you aren't starting with ledger LEFT JOIN .... And as others & I told you, the WHERE removes all rows with NULLs that LEFT JOIN AM added.

Comment: How can I use that where condition with displaying null data. Where condition is very important in it. I tried without where and it is giving output for all ledgers but the AccMaster.Date condition is must @philipxy

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3082/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE AccDetail (DetailID int,
                        MasterID int,
                        LedgerID int,
                        Credit decimal(18, 2));
INSERT INTO AccDetail
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 500);

CREATE TABLE Ledgers (ID int,
                      Name varchar(10),
                      AccGroupID int);
INSERT INTO Ledgers
VALUES (1, 'A', 1),
       (2, 'B', 1);

CREATE TABLE AccMaster (MasterID int,
                        Date date);
INSERT INTO AccMaster
VALUES (1, '2019-11-04'),
       (2, '2019-11-03');

CREATE TABLE AccGroup (ID int,
                       Name varchar(10));
INSERT INTO AccGroup
VALUES (1, 'Accounts'),
       (2, 'Others');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT AL.Name,
       ISNULL(SUM(AD.Credit),0) AS SumOfCredits
FROM  Ledgers AL 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AccDetail AD ON AL.ID = AD.LedgerID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AccMaster AM ON AM.MasterID = AD.MasterID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AccGroup AG ON AG.ID = AL.AccGroupID
     WHERE AM.Date = '2019-11-04' OR AM.Date IS NULL
GROUP BY AL.Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3082/2/0)**:

```
| Name | SumOfCredits |
|------|--------------|
|    A |          500 |
|    B |            0 |
```

Comment: Your answer is correct when there is no where condition with AccMaster. Please check updated question. There is a where condition with AccMaster.Date

Comment: Personally, I'd move the clause on `AM.Date` to the `ON` here.

Comment: Both of your queries doesn't work @xXx. The where condition is important

Comment: What are query 1 & query 2? PS The question doesn't say what output is desired in general, so why is whatever part of this that is an answer supposed to be an answer? PS Unclear questions should be downvoted, close voted & commented on to request clarity, not guessed at.

Comment: @faheemKurikkal if you have checked sql fiddle you will find after execution your expected output that you already updated in your post.Otherwise, your post isn't clear enough, I am trying to give you solutions based on information you afforded.

Comment: @philipxy he keeps updating the post everytime.

Comment: What's your point? It's never been clear & as I just said it should never have been answered, etc. Also it changing has nothing to do with you not saying what 1 & 2 are.

Comment: @faheemKurikkal did you check my answer on sqlfiddle?

Comment: Yes. I checked query1. You can look here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6dcc3/14/0 . Query 2 doesn't include date condition, hence cannot be used @xXx

Comment: @faheemKurikkal in the link you updated your schema which is not matching with your post as you added status for AccMaster and there is no NULL value for Ledger B.You can check my first solution here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3082/1

Comment: 'Status' column doesn't matter, I just tried with it. There is no result for 'B' in your query, because there is no entry in AccDetail for 'B' on that date. But I want to display 'B' even it has no data.@xXx

Comment: @faheemKurikkal In the sql fiddle you sent http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6dcc3/14/0 there is an entry in AccDetail for B (INSERT INTO AccDetail Values(1,1,1,500),(2,2,2,1000);) Can you please focus on my solution in the link ?

Comment: I have checked you fiddle and updated it with : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c278ae/2/0  Added a new entry for B in AccDetail in different date and added where condition for specific accmaster.date. Now I want to get the result as before.  @xXx

Comment: @faheemKurikkal the only solution is to add OR AM.Date IS NULL condition in your query to retrieve unmatched entries in AccDetail for 'B'. I updated my answer.

Comment: Tried with IS NULL, but still the same result. You can check here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c278ae/16/0 @xXx

Comment: @faheemKurikkal check it now : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12b7f/1

Comment: Sorry @xXx your query doesn't satisfy the need. In your query there is only one data in AccDetail and AccMaster. I have updated it with two entries with different date. Now I want result of only one date with all ledgers http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c278ae/16/0

Comment: @faheemKurikkal sorry dude just try to know how to ask a question : https://www.dummies.com/careers/find-a-job/interviews/ten-tips-for-asking-good-questions/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Al.Name,
       SUM(ISNULL(AD.Credit,0))
FROM Ledgers AL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AccDetail AD ON AL.Id = AD.LedgerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AccMaster AM ON AM.MasterID = AD.MasterID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AccGroup AG ON AG.ID = AL.AccGroupID
WHERE AM.Date = '2019-11-04' OR AM.Date IS NULL 
GROUP BY Al.Name
```

Comment: It only gives result for one ledger 'A'. It should display 'B' 0 even there is no entry for B.

Comment: The question doesn't say what output is desired in general, so why is this supposed to be an answer? PS Unclear questions should be downvoted, close voted & commented on to request clarity, not guessed at.